# Google API Directions. How do I set origin and destination to nothing?

Tags: html, google-maps

I'm embedding google maps to my website.

This link is what my website map looks like.
https://gyazo.com/fda645cc29b78ce791d90c878648b180

This is what I want my website to look like.
https://gyazo.com/2093195fd87a6e208c7d4d4510f02e81

This is what I have tried so far:
*(Note: this is all html, no javascript)*

```
<iframe
 width="600"
 height="450"
 frameborder="0" style="border:0"
 src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=(APIKEY)&origin=Oslo+Norway&destination=Telemark+Norway&avoid=tolls|highways"allowfullscreen>
```

But I want something bit different. Basically, what I want is for users to have the option to put in where they are and where they are going.I don't want to have a preset option like the API directions gives me. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Embed API to do that (origin and destination are required parameters in directions mode).

However you can go to http://maps.google.com, set up the map the way you want (with no origin or destination), then click on the "hamburger" menu, click on share or embed map, then the embed map tab and get an `<iframe>` URL that loads a map that looks like you want.

**Example**

From this URL:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir///@59.8937805,10.6450363,11z

Following that process yields this iframe code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed? 
pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d128083.93009419793!2d10.645036343724943!3d59.89378054345609!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m3!3e6!4m0!4m0!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1471120225355"
width="100%"
height="450"
frameborder="0"
style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

live URL:
http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_directions_SO_empty.html

Comment: It did work in some way, but I cant click on the origin or destination. I have to click on more options for me to be able to type. Any way around this so I don't have to leave my website to fix this? Below is what I see.


https://gyazo.com/0007ee42df4140aff018182425527b00